# Unity Player Movement Not Working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script to move my character(player)
The script should be fine and it does not have any errors, although when I press play I try to use the arrows and it does not work and I don't know why.

Here is the code. I appreciate any help you can give me, thanks

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

Direction currentDir;
Vector2 input;
bool isMoving = false;
Vector3 startPos;
Vector3 endPos;
float t;

public float walkSpeed = 3f;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    if (isMoving)
    {
        input = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        if (Mathf.Abs(input.x) > input.y)
            input.y = 0;
        else
            input.x = 0;

        if (input != Vector2.zero)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Move(transform));
        }
    }

}

public IEnumerator Move(Transform entity)
{

    isMoving = true;
    startPos = entity.position;
    t = 0;

    endPos = new Vector3(startPos.x + System.Math.Sign(input.x), startPos.y +
        System.Math.Sign(input.y), startPos.z);

    while (t < 1f)
    {
        t += Time.deltaTime * walkSpeed;
        entity.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endPos, t);
        yield return null;
    }

    isMoving = false;
    yield return 0;

}


enum Direction
{
    North,
    East,
    South,
    West
}
    }
```

Comment: This is so wrong. Repeatedly starting `Move` coroutine in the Update function..... You are trying to move like as in FPS game?

Comment: I am trying to make it move like a 2D game. For the sake of argument lets say like Pokemon :)

Comment: Ok I see. This might be ok if that's the case. How do you determine to stop moving/destination position? I think you should explain when the player starts moving? Maybe when the mouse is clicked?

Comment: I am fairly new to Unity so I don't know if I might be able to explain everything in detail. Basically I followed an example online. In the example the person explaining is able to move it with the arrows, since I hear click sounds.... So, I don't know what it is that he did because he didn't assign any specific keys. Or am I missing something and it should work? I am really puzzled to be honest.

Comment: Try to use [GetKeyDown()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html) instead of Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), and as an advice for you, learn unity by trying your own code and visiting the documantation every time you get stuck. In my opinion copying code from tutorials is not helpful

Comment: Yes, like @Programmer says do not call a coroutine every frame as it will generate lots of garbage which needs to be collected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
void Update()
{
    if (isMoving)
    {
```

to

```
void Update()
{
    if (!isMoving)
    {
```

Otherwise, on each Update you check your isMoving variable and do nothing if it is false. The only place where isMoving could become true is your Move coroutine, but it could only be launched from Update, which does not do anything since isMoving is false.

Comment: Thanks  That actually makes sense. Just one problem I faced: If I press the arrows to move it, it disappears o.O Any thoughts on that?